# recover lost files after online LVM resize

Tags: data-recovery, lvm, ext4

I did the following 5 days ago which may have triggered the problem.

```
sudo lvextend -L +20GB /dev/vg1/filme
sudo resize2fs /dev/vg1/filme
```

Now I realize, that almost all files disappeared. Only the directory structure and some newer files are still available.

```
Output from: e2fsck -nfv /dev/vg1/filme

e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

   49906 inodes used (0.07%, out of 69148672)
       0 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
      17 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
         # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
         Extent depth histogram: 49891/7
 5893268 blocks used (2.13%, out of 276576256)
       0 bad blocks
       1 large file

      10 regular files
   49887 directories
       0 character device files
       0 block device files
       0 fifos
       0 links
       0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
       0 sockets
   49897 files
```

Any hint how to recover the files and how to analyze what went wrong?